# What is the fastest way to parse large CSV files into arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a few large CSV files that contain roughly 285 columns.
There are over a million lines between the files.

To parse each line, I am using `fgets` which works quickly.
From there, I have tried using `str_getcsv` on the line, which averages 0.001421 seconds per line. This doesn't sound like much, but once you do 1,000,000 lines, that's 1421 seconds or roughly 24 minutes.
To speed up the process, I do as much comparison as I can with the strings before attempting to parse the CSV. If my checks deem it irrelevant, then it skips the line.

My problem comes when I need the indexed values to do more advanced comparisons of the data.
Is `str_getcsv` the fastest option, or is there a faster method to get the lines into an array?
My first thought was to use explode, but the data has quoted values and some values contain commas as well.
I only need to work with one line at a time, if that helps with any parsing rules.

Comment: dont describe code, post it in the question

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a solution for myself, but I am curious if anyone else can test this against a larger data set?
Parsing the lines using `str_getcsv` resulted in an average of 0.0014 seconds.
Parsing with this code resulted in an average of 0.0002 seconds.
It definitely could use additional work to provide more flexibility, but for the sake of a simple CSV with quoted values, this works fine for my purposes.

```
function _csv2array($line) {
  $ret = [0 => '']; //Start with an empty array
  $idx = 0; //First index
  $lastpos = 0; //No commas found yet
  while (($pos = strpos($line, ',', $lastpos)) !== FALSE) { //While we find another comma
    $ret[$idx].= substr($line, $lastpos, $pos-$lastpos); //Add it to our current index
    if (substr($ret[$idx], 0, 1) == '"') { //If we started with a quote
      if (substr($ret[$idx], -1) == '"') { //Are we ending in a quote?
        $qts = substr_count($ret[$idx], '"') % 2; //Are there an even number of quotes?
        if (!$qts) { //If there's an even amount of quotes, safe to close out this field
          $ret[$idx] = trim($ret[$idx], '"'); //Remove the outer quotes
          $ret[++$idx] = ''; //Start the next index
        } else $ret[$idx].= ','; //Still inside a quoted field, don't ignore this comma, append it
      } else $ret[$idx].= ','; //Still inside a quoted field, don't ignore this comma, append it
    } else { //Non quoted field
      $ret[++$idx] = ''; //Advance to next index
    }
    $lastpos = $pos+1; //Start our next search AFTER this comma
  }
  $ret[$idx].= substr($line, $lastpos); //Add whatever's after the last ,
  $ret[$idx] = trim($ret[$idx], "\"\r\n"); //Remove any newlines/surrounding quotes
  return $ret; //Return the array
}
```